# Are MongoDB facet sub-pipelines asynchronous and run in parallel?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We can create `$facet` in MongoDB aggregations. Each `$facet` can have multiple sub-pipelines. However, does these sub-pipelines run in parallel and asynchronously?

Comment: You would probably get an answer faster by testing this out.

Comment: How can I test whether it is happening in parallel? Please guide

Comment: Run a query that takes a long time with 2 pipelines, measure execution time, run another query that returns the same amount of data with 1 pipeline, measure execution time, run a query with the same amount of data & 4 pipelines, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Are MongoDB facet sub-pipelines asynchronous and run in parallel?

No, all aggregation pipelines are executed sequentially, including $facet.

Significantly, the database's Aggregation framework processes each facet's sub-pipeline serially.

If you’re prepared to add some complexity and overhead to your client code, there is a blog post that shows how multi-faceted MongoDB aggregations can be sped up by encouraging parallelism, from the client application's perspective using custom code:

[Paul Done's Technical Blog: Run MongoDB Aggregation Facets In Parallel For Faster Insight](http://pauldone.blogspot.com/2018/02/parallel-mongodb-aggregation-facets.html)